# PyCharm: How to download libraries to specific folder?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I would like to download libraries, via the PyCharm interface, but to a specific folder.

How can I do this?

An image of PyCharm's download interface is Attached.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That is a nice picture of PyCharm package management, but doesn't really add anything useful to the question :-)

Comment: That explains the meaning of " PyCharm's download interface"..

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, was trying to jokingly point out that people knowing enough about PyCharm to answer will know exactly what you mean without the picture. As for the question, you can't, to my knowledge, install packages to a random directory. What are you trying to achieve? If it is installing to a virtual environment, you just have to select that environment in the `Project Interpreter`, and you're good to go.